# Calling 2 joined functions in one Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to know how to chain two scopes from my Match model, here are the two scopes:

```
public function scopeMainMatches($query){
    return $query->where('matches.type','main');
}
```

---

```
public function scopeDotaMatches($query,$type){
    return $query
            ->join('leagues','leagues.id','=','matches.id')
            ->select('matches.*')
            ->where('leagues.type',$type);
}
```

here is my Controller which returns the ID league of the table leagues:

```
public function showDotaMatches($ptr){   
    $_matches = \App\Match::mainMatches()
                            ->whereNotIn('status',['ongoing','open'])
                            ->get()
                            ->load('league','teamA', 'teamB')
                            ->where('league_id','1')
                            ->sortByDesc('schedule')
                            ->slice($ptr, 10);
```

what I want to happen is this:

```
public function showDotaMatches($ptr,$request){
    $_matches = \App\Match::mainMatches()
                            ->dotaMatches($request-type)
                            ->where('leagues.type','dota2') // instead of ('league_id','1')
```

to make the code clean. but when I did chain the two scopes, it says SQL constraint violation since both matches table and leagues table has status and type in it. anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: edit: league_id belongs to matches table, it just has a eloquent relationship on table leagues

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after a `whereHas` query:

```
// Retrieve all matches with at least one league with the type 'dota2'
$matches = App\Match::whereHas('leagues', function ($query) {
    $query->where('type', 'dota2');
})->get();
```

You then wouldn't need your join in `scopeDotaMatches`.

Comment: but how am I supposed to input all the query including the ->whereNotIn('status.. to ->slice($ptr,10); ? because I'm getting an error such as "BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefine method Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder::leagues(); "

tho I've already inputted above the use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder

Comment: Can you add your model relations code to your question?